# How can I link the sockets in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have 4 sockets in a room. How can I link the sockets? I want to use it like this:

```
socket1 = param1;
socket2 = param2;
socket3 = param3;
socket4 = param4;

allSockets = ???

allSockets.on('', function(...)...)
```

Comment: You can broadcast/emit to all members of a room.  I'm not aware of any way to apply a listener that listens only to those sockets in a room without attaching a listener to each socket in the room.

Comment: And how can I listen all, if i get it in 4 parameters?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "if I get in 4 parameters".  If you're trying to implement a specific function signature, please show how that function is declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast/emit to all members of a room. I'm not aware of any way to apply a listener that listens only to those sockets in a room without attaching a separate listener to each socket in the room.

I can think of a couple alternative implementations:

If you have an array of sockets that you want to apply listeners to, then you can just iterate through the array and add listeners:

```
function addListeners(sockets, msg, fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
        sockets[i].on(msg, fn);
    }
}
```

It might also be possible to add the listener to all sockets, but only process the message if the socket is actually in a particular rooom:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on("msg", function(data) {
        // here check if this socket is actually in the desired room
        // if so, process the message
        // if not, ignore the message
    });
});
```